# Does a GraphQL API have better performance than standard RESTful APIs in terms of speed?

Tags: javascript, performance, rest, asynchronous, graphql

I was exploring the performance of GraphQL vs RESTful APIs and wanted to know which is faster for the client?

Will the client notice any difference? Which scenarios does GraphQL excel in - in terms of performance, in comparison to standard RESTful APIs?

Comment: There's too many factors here to give a concise answer. A single REST call will probably be faster than a single GraphQL call, but it's hard to make a real-world comparison. The devil is in the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, no.

### Will the client notice any difference?

That depends entirely on how well the GraphQL system is implemented.  With GraphQL, caching is up to the developer and this presents a potential for performance regressions compared with a 'well-implemented' REST system.

### Which scenarios does GraphQL excel in - in terms of performance, in comparison to standard RESTful APIs?

I am not aware of any scenarios where GraphQL is used purely for performance gains.